# Linq to recurse through a hierarchy

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a heirarchical data structure as follows.

TABLE 1

```
id | Groupname | parentId
```

TABLE 2

```
id | nodeName | parentId
```

Table 1 parentId refers to table1 Id, and table2 parentId also refers to table 1 id.

Starting at any ID in table 1, I need to print out all the nodes, and then traverse through the children of all child groups.

Up to now I have this

```
int id = 1; // replace with argument

repository.Nodes.Where(n => n.ParentId == Id).ToList().ForEach(d =>
{
  result.NodeList.Add(GetNodeDetails(n.Id));
});
```

Can anyone help me get this looping through in nice efficent linq manner?

Comment: So you want to flatten the hierarchy, is that right?

Comment: How do you get the children of a node? Is there a navigation property?

Comment: Yes I want to flatten, and yes there are navigation properties. Thanks.

Comment: `repository.Nodes` is already the flattened list of all nodes.

Comment: @dtb: He doesn't want all nodes. He only wants the subset that are children of `Id`.

Comment: nodes is a flat list already, with each belonging to a particular group. The groups table has foreigjn key with itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to flatten the hierarchy, i.e. the end result should be one flat list with all children of all hierarchy levels.

The simplest way to achieve this is through recursion:

```
private IEnumerable<Node> GetSelfAndChildren(Node node)
{
    yield return GetNodeDetails(n.Id);
    foreach(var c in n.Children.SelectMany(GetSelfAndChildren)
        yield return c;
};


var result = repository.Nodes.Where(n => n.ParentId == Id)
                       .AsEnumerable()
                       .SelectMany(GetSelfAndChildren)
                       .ToList();
```

This uses a recursive method to get a flat list of children.

This approach has the potential to exhibit the N+1 problem. Depending on the configuration each access of `Children` will cause a roundtrip to the database.
If the N+1 problem is happening and causing - well - problems, an alternative approach would be to first fetch *all* nodes from the database and then perform a [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Comment: Thanks Daniel, Ill give this a go and let you know.

Comment: When you say it can only be achieved by recursion do you mean with the restriction that it be done without loops? Also +1 for using `yield return` so that I finally start using it :)

Comment: @roliu: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. My code clearly has a loop. But you can't achieve it with *only* a loop - at least not easily.

Comment: Isn't it just a BFS? What prevents you from using the queue implementation that is iterative? And I see why you're confused (I ignored the `foreach` for some reason). I guess I just don't understand why you claim it can only be done with recursion.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I get the error "The yield statement cannot be used inside an anonymous method or lambda expression" Could you help, because this code is way beyond me Im afraid.

Comment: @DavidB: Please see update, I changed the lambda to a method.

Comment: @roliu: I reworded that part. I guess BFS could be used, you are right. I am not particularly strong in graph theory so I just didn't think about it. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Thanks thats great. Ill accpet your answer.

Comment: @DavidB: You say the code is beyond you. Do you have anything in particular that needs explaining?

Comment: @Daniel It makes more sense now its a method, Im going to look at the yield statement and really try to get around anonymous fucntions.

Comment: @DavidB: Alright. Yes, look at yield. That's the keyword that powers LINQ to Objects and its deferred execution.

Comment: Thanks for this, its nice to see someone so free with their knowledge.